# Camelize function output not displayed, no error thrown

Tags: javascript

I have a very basic HTML, user enters something like -webkit-transition and the function returns something like WebkitTransition.

```
<div id='app'>Change input to camelCase</div>
<input id='getInput' />
<button id='submit' />get result</button>
<span id="output">Result: </span>
```

The relevant JS is this:

```
//   initializing the input field value var  let inputed = getInput.value;


 // this is the function, it should take the input.value as argument
  function whatComesOut (str) {
  return str
    .split('-') 
    .map( 
      (word, index) => index == 0 ? word : word[0].toUpperCase() + word.slice(1)
    ) 
    .join(''); 
}

 // updating the input value on change, this logs the correct input value
 getInput.addEventListener('change', function(e){
 let inputed = e.target.value;
 console.log(inputed);

  })
 // on click I want to display the returned value from the function in the span element
 submit.addEventListener('click', function(){

 console.log(inputed);
 output.innerHTML += whatComesOut(inputed); 
 })
```

But, nothing is happening, no errors in the console either.

A link to codepen
https://codepen.io/damPop/pen/PxYvJr?editors=0010

The question is, how do i get the return value from the whatComesOut function displayed in the span element? Do i need the pass the event object somewhere?

Comment: `inputted` is local only to the change event callback.

Comment: submit buttons submit....

Comment: o0, this is what happens when I am still used to use var:-)

Comment: Also change the button type to "button"

Comment: the same would have happened with `var`, it all depends on where you define your variable.

Comment: All true. It still does not work, either the function does not run or the argument is not passed.

Comment: The click function, it does not have access to the variable inputted, logs nothing. Therefore, no argument is passed into whatComesOut.
The function listening to the change event does have access to the inputed variable. So, how can this be resolved

Comment: https://codepen.io/nagasai/details/bQbPXL, issue is with the inputed variable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue here is that unlike in the event listener on `getInput`, the value of `inputed` is not declared in the `submit` event listener, so it uses the static value that was assigned on line 5. If you add `const inputed = getInput.value;` right before `output.innerHTML += whatComesOut(inputed);` this will work.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make the variable inputed global instead of local to only the event listener function.
Also, change the type of your button to "button" so it does not submit the form and refresh the page.

```
//   initializing the input field value var  let inputed = getInput.value;

 let inputed; 
 // this is the function, it should take the input.value as argument
  function whatComesOut (str) {
  return str.split('-').map( 
      (word, index) => index == 0 ? word : word[0].toUpperCase() + word.slice(1)
    ).join(''); 
}

 // updating the input value on change, this logs the correct input value
 getInput.addEventListener('change', function(e){
  inputed = e.target.value;
 console.log(inputed);

  })
 // on click I want to display the returned value from the function in the span element
 submit.addEventListener('click', function(){

 console.log(inputed);
 output.innerHTML += whatComesOut(inputed); 
 })
```

Comment: Thanks, however this still does not work. No error either

Comment: Got it, but this was never a submit button...Or I misunderstood your vague statement. All that was needed was let inputed = getInput.value; within the click handler.

Comment: <Button> is a submit button, they submit forms

Comment: Changed it just  for you:-)

Answer (score 0):

You've declared a global variable **inputted** And which was redeclare in one of The Event,
So this makes the initialization strict within the Event ( local scope ). The initialization to the local scope variable made no changes to the global variable.

```
var global = 'it's global now'

function func() { var local = 'its local variable'}
```

The global scope variable is accessible within the local scope and you could make changes to it since It wasn't **a constant declaration**.

Remove the let in **line 19, erase line 26** and remove string concatenation to avoid repetition in **line 28** it should work.

```
getInput.addEventListener('change', function(e){
  inputed = e.target.value;

})

  submit.addEventListener('click', function(){

   output.innerHTML = camelise(inputed); 
 })
```